# Why is the value in a List<T> changed when the copies in an ObservableCollection are?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, microsoft-metro, observablecollection

```
// Get list from DB    
List<Category> dbCategories = DatabaseWrapper.GetCategories();
...
// COPY values to Obs.Col.
var shownCategries = new ObservableCollection<Category>(dbCategories);

// This also changes the value in 'dbCatagories'.
shownCategories[0].Name = "Hej";
```

I want to be able to change a value in the obs.col. without changing the same value in dbCategories. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong since the 2nd line of code should be a copy constructor?

Comment: No surprise here. read about [reference types and value types](http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing can explain more than source code. You're making invalid assumptions.

Namely:

```
private void CopyFrom(IEnumerable<T> collection)
{
  IList<T> items = this.Items;
  if (collection == null || items == null)
    return;
  foreach (T obj in collection)
    items.Add(obj);
}
```

and

```
public ObservableCollection(List<T> list)
  : base(list != null ? (IList<T>) new List<T>(list.Count) : (IList<T>) list)
{
  this.CopyFrom((IEnumerable<T>) list);
}
```

as you can see, "copy constructor" indeed does make copy of LIST object itself, **but it does not make copy of individual list elements.** Note, it's not that simple, your example could actually work if Category would be [struct](http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx).

This is usual behaviour, and it's called **shallow copying.** Alternatively, what you are looking is called **deep copying**

You need to create manually copies, either using serialization, or just create copy-constructor in *Category* class.

This would be good example:

```
new ObservableCollection(dbCategories.Select(x => new Category(x)).ToList());
```